# Clicking on one of many views with same id in Espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a layout (A) that includes another layout (B) multiple times. Layout B contains a button with id `R.id.my_button`. As a result, layout A contains many of those buttons with the same id.

How do I test clicking on any of those buttons with espresso?

`onView(withId(R.id.my_button)).perform(click());` doesn't really do anything in this case.

Comment: You may set tag to button which identify buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably, your layout B contains also some unique information, let's say `TextView` with `unique name`. In this case your code will look like this:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.my_button), hasSibling(withText("unique name")))).perform(click());
```

More examples can be found in [Espresso Wiki # ViewMatchers](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples#ViewMatchers).