# Clicking one view of many views with same id in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a layout (A) that includes another layout (B) multiple times. Layout B contains a button with id R.id.my_button. As a result, layout A contains many of those buttons with the same id.

How do I test clicking on any of those buttons with espresso?

My only one unique information is I know where the layout B in layout A (B is in the layout my_layout1 for example.)

unlike this, I have not unique information. 
[Clicking on one of many views with same id in Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354340/clicking-on-one-of-many-views-with-same-id-in-espresso)
also, I tried this,
[onChildView and hasSiblings with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848620/onchildview-and-hassiblings-with-espresso)

Answer (score 1):

Temporarly, i tag the buttons everytime I add a view and in espresso i used         `onView(withTagValue(is((Object) "mytag1"))).perform(click());`